# Powershell base64 content added as mail attachment destroys the text format

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have a script like below that runs in Azure automation as runbook. The runbook simply gets a list of firewall rules, appends it into a text file after base64 encoding it and then sends the text file as an attachment in the mail.

Problem here is when the base64 encoding happen, the format of the file is destroyed and all separate lines are grouped into a single line.

My Script:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

# SendGrid Code

# Hardcode the API key of sendgrid. We need it in the header of the API call
$SENDGRID_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create the headers for the API call
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $SENDGRID_API_KEY)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

# Parameters for sending the email
$fromEmailAddress = "mytest@gmail.com"
$destEmailAddress = "mytest123@gmail.com"
$subject = "Testemail send from runbook via SendGrid"
Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -ServerName "test-server101" | Out-File testout.txt

$content = "Please find attach the list of Client IPs for SQL server."

$FileContent = get-content testout.txt
$ConvertToBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($FileContent)
$EncodedFile = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ConvertToBytes)

# Create a JSON message with the parameters from above
$body = @{
personalizations = @(
    @{
        to = @(
                @{
                    email = $destEmailAddress
                }
        )
    }
)
from = @{
    email = $fromEmailAddress
}
subject = $subject
content = @(
    @{
        type = "text/plain"
        value = $content
    }
)
"attachments" = @(
                                    @{
                                        "content"=$EncodedFile
                                        "filename"='testout.txt'
                                        "type"= 'text/html'
                                        "disposition"="attachment"
                                     }
               )
}

# Convert the string into a real JSON-formatted string
# Depth specifies how many levels of contained objects
# are included in the JSON representation. The default
# value is 2
$bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

# Call the SendGrid RESTful web service and pass the
# headers and json message. More details about the
# webservice and the format of the JSON message go to
# https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $bodyJson
```

Attachment received looks like below.

> ResourceGroup xxx Ipaddress 4.5.6.7 rulename testrule blah blah ResourceGroup abc IPadrress 3.4.5.67 rulename blah blah ResourceGroup qwerty Ipaddress 4.5.6.7 rulename testrule blah blah

Actual output in the text file or desired:

`ResourceGroup xxx Ipaddress 4.5.6.7 rulename testrule blah blah`

`ResourceGroup xxx Ipaddress 4.5.6.7 rulename testrule blah blah`

`ResourceGroup xxx Ipaddress 4.5.6.7 rulename testrule blah blah`

Any idea that could help me retain this format? I was thinking of using some string -replace things to add aline break before the base64 value of every "ResourceGroup" in the match

Comment: Could you try `$FileContent = Get-Content -Path testout.txt -Raw`?

Comment: @Theo you made my day. It works. Thank you